# Camera Preview is displaying a black screen

Tags: android, camera

```
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("OnResume", "Camera has been resumed");

        try {
               mCamera = Camera.open();
            Log.d("OnResume", "Camera has been opened");
            mCamera.startPreview();
            Log.d("OnResume", "Camera has started preview");
            preview.setCamera(mCamera);
            Log.d("OnResume", "setCamera");
            }   catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            Log.d("OnResume", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Getting error while mCamera=Camera.open() is called.It is not able to connect to the camera services. Inspit of using all the permission in the manifest file.

```
 Error while opening the camera and camera services

    D/OnResume﹕ Camera has been resumed.

    W/CameraBase﹕ An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0.

    D/OnResume﹕ Fail to connect to camera service

    Getting error in inside try block. Have used the camera permission in manifest file.
```

Comment: have you define this  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> permission in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Error it self hint about problem,your missing to add camera permission in AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Also add [uses-feature](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html) if required :

```
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
```